# Admob overall Match Rate is very low. Only around 3%

Tags: android, kotlin, admob

I am requesting an interstitial ad first time when the app is started. Show ad after visiting 4 activities as following code.

```
if (adFreeCount == 4) {
    loadFullScreenAds(activity)
    adFreeCount = 0
} else if (adFreeCount == 3) {
    if (!mInterstitialAd.isLoading && !mInterstitialAd.isLoaded) {
        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(AdRequest.Builder().build())
    }
    adFreeCount++
} else {
    adFreeCount++
}
```

When `onAdClosed` or `onAdFailedToLoad`, I request the ad as like following.

```
mInterstitialAd.adListener = object : AdListener() {
    override fun onAdLoaded() {
    }

    override fun onAdFailedToLoad(errorCode: Int) {
        if (!mInterstitialAd.isLoading && !mInterstitialAd.isLoaded) {
            mInterstitialAd.loadAd(AdRequest.Builder().build())
        }
    }

    override fun onAdClosed() {
        if (!mInterstitialAd.isLoading && !mInterstitialAd.isLoaded) {
            mInterstitialAd.loadAd(AdRequest.Builder().build())
        }
    }
}
if (!mInterstitialAd.isLoading && !mInterstitialAd.isLoaded) {
    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(AdRequest.Builder().build())
}
```

Might possible, there was problem with my integration where my app was sending unnecessary interestitials ad requests which tripped in Admob system. But I am not sure what is happening.

I am also not able to find solution online.

[image]